# how can I fix boot error status 0xc000000e on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot

First,I wanna clarify that I found few answers @ superuser.com but none of them worked for me.So,please if somebody know how to fix my computer problem,let me know.
Few days ago,I started my laptop computer and saw the error.The error says

```
Windows failed to start.A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.
If windows files have been damaged or configured incorrectly,startup repair can help       diagnose and fix the problem.If power was interrupted during startup ,choose start windows normally.
   Launch startup repair(recommended)
   Start windows normally
Description:Fix problems that are preventing windows from starting
```

After I choose either of them,it redirects me to another page.

```
1.Insert your windows installation disc and restart your computer
2.Choose your language setting,and then click Next
3.Select "Repair your computer".

status:0xc000000e
Boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

I tried using DVD/CD and USB Drive.But it doesn't get any connection from DVD drive or USB port.I also tried using f8 to use command prompt.But when I select command prompt,it send me on that page again(1st page).So,basically,whichever option I choose,it redirect me on that 2 pages back and forth.

I will appreciate your help in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Either your HDD died or the boot partition (somethimes windows creates these) went missing/corrupted. Can you extract your HDD and check it on another computer?, chances are that it broke or the partition table got messed up. How exactly did this happened? is there something you did prior to this fail?

Comment: Thanks for your response.I really did nothing.I was just starting my laptop.

Comment: If this really helped you mark the answer as accepted so other users could help themselves if they got the same problem. And let me know if you could check it on another computer to know the state of your drive.

Answer (score 0):

I diconnected all external devices. The problem was a damaged jack for the speakers. I replaced it, and the problem was fixed

Comment: This looks like an answer to some other question, not this one.